# Error when starting spark-shell local on Mac

Tags: apache-spark

I get the following error when I try to start spark-shell locally on Mac. Because the error occurs while sc is being created, sc is not available afterwards.

```
[ender@koders:data] $ spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
16/12/29 13:57:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/29 13:57:12 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:31)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:94)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index 38: spark://fe80:0:0:0:44cd:86ff:fe5b:cd90%7:61707/classes
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(URI.java:2978)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(URI.java:3001)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3142)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:48)
    ... 63 more
16/12/29 13:57:12 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1798)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1797)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:31)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:94)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/12/29 13:57:12 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index 38: spark://fe80:0:0:0:44cd:86ff:fe5b:cd90%7:61707/classes
  at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(URI.java:2978)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(URI.java:3001)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3142)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
  at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.<init>(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:48)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:453)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:497)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2275)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)


  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
  ... 47 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> sc
<console>:18: error: not found: value sc
       sc
       ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and investigating the logs, I suspected that it's because my hostname could not be found in /etc/hosts. After changing the hostname from "koders.local" to "koders" which exists inside /etc/hosts, problem solved.

Comment: having the same issue but does not work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914586/spark-fails-to-start-in-local-mode-when-disconnected-possible-bug-in-handling-i