# Spark fails to start in local mode when disconnected [Possible bug in handling IPv6 in Spark??]

Tags: macos, shell, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

The problem is the same as described here [Error when starting spark-shell local on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381293/error-when-starting-spark-shell-local-on-mac)

... but I have failed to find a solution. I also used to get the malformed URI error but now I get expected hostname.

So when I am not connected to internet, spark shell fails to load in local mode [See the error below]. So I am running Apache Spark 2.1.0 downloaded from internet, running on my Mac. So I run `./bin/spark-shell` and it gives me the error below.

So I have read the Spark code and it is using Java's `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` to find the localhost's IP address. So when I am connected to internet, I get back an IPv4 with my local hostname.

```
scala> InetAddress.getLocalHost
res9: java.net.InetAddress = AliKheyrollahis-MacBook-Pro.local/192.168.1.26
```

**but the key is**, when disconnected, I get an IPv6 with a percentage in the values (it is scoped):

```
scala> InetAddress.getLocalHost
res10: java.net.InetAddress = AliKheyrollahis-MacBook-Pro.local/fe80:0:0:0:2b9a:4521:a301:e9a5%10
```

And this IP is the same as the one you see in the error message. I feel my problem is that it throws Spark since it cannot handle `%10` in the result.

My guess is this is a bug, probably witnessed by very few since people always connected to internet or their mac does not return a scoped IPv6. Even if I can configure my Mac to get around this issue, I am happy. I have done anything including setting IPv6 to manual or Link-local only to no avail.

[image]

I have also tried removing `::1 localhost` line in `/etc/hosts` to no avail.

So here is the full error with DEBUG output (please note the same IPv6 being used to listen):

```
7/01/28 22:02:59 DEBUG ShutdownHookManager: Adding shutdown hook
17/01/28 22:03:06 DEBUG Shell: setsid is not available on this machine. So not using it.
17/01/28 22:03:06 DEBUG Shell: setsid exited with exit code 0
17/01/28 22:03:06 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/01/28 22:03:06 DEBUG MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName=Ops, always=false, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
17/01/28 22:03:06 DEBUG MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName=Ops, always=false, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
17/01/28 22:03:06 DEBUG MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(sampleName=Ops, always=false, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[GetGroups], valueName=Time)
17/01/28 22:03:06 DEBUG MetricsSystemImpl: UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
17/01/28 22:03:26 DEBUG KerberosName: Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
17/01/28 22:03:26 DEBUG Groups:  Creating new Groups object
17/01/28 22:03:26 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
17/01/28 22:03:26 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader: Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
17/01/28 22:03:26 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader: java.library.path=/Users/aliostad/torch/install/lib:/Users/aliostad/torch/install/lib:/Users/aliostad/torch/install/lib:/Users/aliostad/torch/install/lib:/Users/aliostad/torch/install/lib:/Users/aliostad/torch/install/lib:/Users/aliostad/torch/install/lib::/Users/aliostad/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
17/01/28 22:03:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/01/28 22:03:26 DEBUG PerformanceAdvisory: Falling back to shell based
17/01/28 22:03:26 DEBUG JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation: hadoop login
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: aliostad
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation: Using user: "UnixPrincipal: aliostad" with name aliostad
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation: User entry: "aliostad"
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:aliostad (auth:SIMPLE)
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: aliostad
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: aliostad
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(aliostad); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(aliostad); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG SecurityManager: Created SSL options for fs: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()}
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG InternalLoggerFactory: Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent0: java.nio.Buffer.address: available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent0: sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent0: sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent0: direct buffer constructor: available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent0: java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent0: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG Cleaner0: java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: Java version: 8
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: sun.misc.Unsafe: available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: Javassist: available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /var/folders/pz/vgqg2gns18j_kxsnkzrp6x_m0000gn/T (java.io.tmpdir)
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: io.netty.maxDirectMemory: 0 bytes
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator: Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageMatcher
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator: Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.io.netty.buffer.ByteBufMatcher
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG MultithreadEventLoopGroup: -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG NioEventLoop: -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG NioEventLoop: -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PlatformDependent: org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 8
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 8
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator: -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG ThreadLocalRandom: -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0x3185a000d3a47bd4 (took 1 ms)
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG ByteBufUtil: -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG ByteBufUtil: -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG ByteBufUtil: -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG NetUtil: Loopback interface: lo0 (lo0, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG NetUtil: /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: 128 (non-existent)
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG TransportServer: Shuffle server started on port: 56107
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 56107.
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG SparkEnv: Using serializer: class org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/01/28 22:03:27 DEBUG MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: init
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/01/28 22:03:27 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/pz/vgqg2gns18j_kxsnkzrp6x_m0000gn/T/blockmgr-4079e45b-e4e0-4386-bffe-42af18634710
17/01/28 22:03:28 DEBUG DiskBlockManager: Adding shutdown hook
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/01/28 22:03:28 DEBUG OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: init
17/01/28 22:03:28 DEBUG SecurityManager: Created SSL options for ui: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()}
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://fe80:0:0:0:2b9a:4521:a301:e9a5%10:4040
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO Executor: Using REPL class URI: spark://fe80:0:0:0:2b9a:4521:a301:e9a5%10:56107/classes
17/01/28 22:03:28 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Expected hostname
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.checkHost(Utils.scala:931)
    at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://fe80:0:0:0:2b9a:4521:a301:e9a5%10:4040
17/01/28 22:03:28 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1826)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/01/28 22:03:28 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/01/28 22:03:28 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Expected hostname
  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.checkHost(Utils.scala:931)
  at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:31)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
  ... 47 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

Comment: Reported as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19394

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, I seem to be able to get around it by passing configuration directly `--conf spark.driver.host=localhost`

So I run:

```
./bin/spark-shell --conf spark.driver.host=localhost
```

Still if there is a better solution, please let me know.

---

## [UPDATE]

Jacek Laskowski [confirmed](https://twitter.com/jaceklaskowski/status/825663194559553536) this is probably the only available solution for now.

Answer (score 5):

To those who are working with spark through sbt and having the same issue. Just add .set("spark.driver.host", "localhost") to your SparkConf() so initialisation of spark context will look like this:

```
val conf = 
    new SparkConf()
    .setAppName( "temp1" )
    .setMaster( "local" )
    .set( "spark.driver.host", "localhost" )

val sc = 
    SparkContext
    .getOrCreate( conf )
```

This initial configuration must be done before any other getOrCreate of SparkContext.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to check is probably `/etc/hosts`. Make sure that you have the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
```

---

If the above does not work, then the following should do the trick:

```
 sudo hostname -s 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while using the SharedSparkContext with my tests.
Adding those two lines (in my beforeAll method) as @dennis suggested solved the problem for me :

```
  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    sc.getConf.setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
  }
```

I hope this will be solved in the next versions of Spark.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pyspark, use the config method to set the host driver to localhost.

```
spark = (SparkSession
              .builder
              .appName( "temp1" )
              .config( "spark.driver.host", "localhost" )
              .getOrCreate()
              )
```